# How to say "<some noun> looks/seems/appears <adjective>?"

Tags: grammar

How would I say something like this:

1. That car looks new.
2. That bike seems difficult to ride.
3. The challenge appears very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use (V)어 보이다 or (N)처럼 보이다 for that.

1. 저 차 새 것처럼 보인다.
2. 저 자전거 타기 힘들게 생겼다.
3. 그 문제는 엄청 쉬울 것 같다.

-게 생기다, -ㄹ 것 같다 etc works too.